# Why didn't Zawe Ashton stay on Sherlock as Sally Donovan?

Tags: casting, sherlock

Sally Donovan was portrayed by Vinette Robinson throughout the series except for the unaired pilot (s1e0).

Why didn't Zawe Ashton remain on Sherlock?

Looking at their filmographies, Zawe Ashton might have been too busy with three films in 2011 while Vinette Robinson has no films in the year 2011.

But I couldn't find any statements on the topic.

Comment: Parts get recast all the time.

Comment: Between pilot and show production, without making another pilot? I wish somebody had the time to lay down some statistics on that - "how common are recasts after pilot production"

Comment: *Especially* between (unaired) pilot and show. *Game Of Thrones* recast several roles, and there are even series where actors in the aired pilot were recast when the show went to series. https://uproxx.com/viral/famous-tv-characters-recast-pilot/ , https://decider.com/2018/10/09/sitcoms-roles-recast-after-pilot/ , https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a828570/tv-actors-axed-after-the-pilot/ , https://www.looper.com/97859/tv-roles-recast-pilot/ , https://screenrant.com/characters-recast-after-pilot/ , https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/catch-tv-characters-were-recast-191443453.html , etc.